# How to make to_number ignore non-numerical values

Tags: sql, oracle

Column xy of type 'nvarchar2(40)' in table ABC.

Column consists mainly of numerical Strings

how can I make a

```
select to_number(trim(xy)) from ABC
```

query, that ignores non-numerical strings?

Comment: See this thread - some examples have been given: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21187819/oracle-sql-query-to-obtain-the-maximum-value-of-a-column-that-has-been-converted/21188117#21188117

Comment: Define "numerical".  For example, in Oracle `+1.2e-3f` is a valid number, but none of the answers below would correctly recognize it.

Answer (score 1):

In general in relational databases, the order of evaluation is not defined, so it is possible that the `select` functions are called before the `where` clause filters the data.  I know this is the case in SQL Server.  [Here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3aNO%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:5744144426828) is a post that suggests that the same can happen in Oracle.

The `case` statement, however, does cascade, so it is evaluated in order.  For that reason, I prefer:

```
select (case when NOT regexp_like(xy,'[^[:digit:]]') then to_number(xy)
        end)
from ABC;
```

This will return `NULL` for values that are not numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regexp_like to find out if it is a number (with/without plus/minus sign, decimal separator followed by at least one digit, thousand separators in the correct places if any) and use it like this:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER( CASE WHEN regexp_like(xy,'.....') THEN xy ELSE NULL END )
FROM ABC;
```

However, as the built-in function TO_NUMBER is not able to deal with all numbers (it fails at least when a number contains thousand separators), I would suggest to write a PL/SQL function TO_NUMBER_OR_DEFAULT(numberstring, defaultnumber) to do what you want.

EDIT: You may want to read my answer on using regexp_like to determine if a string contains a number here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21235443/2270762.

Answer (score -1):

You can add WHERE

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(TRIM(xy)) FROM ABC WHERE REGEXP_INSTR(email, '[A-Za-z]') = 0
```

The WHERE is ignoring columns with letters. See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm)